# Android FileNotFoundException even if file is available and permission set

Tags: java, android, filenotfoundexception

I'm saving an Image taken by camera to the external storage. Later on I want to upload the image to our servers.

There I try to recreate the file from path but always a FileNotFoundException appears.

```
File file = new File("file:/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instantley/IMG_20160523_170354803382833.jpg");
```

I already checked:

- File is available (took a lookup into the photos app and checked the url)
- Set permission for external read in the manifest
- requested runtime permission

  `Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
  05-23 17:04:33.014 1918-1918/com.instantley.messenger W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
  05-23 17:04:33.014 1918-1918/com.instantley.messenger W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
  05-23 17:04:33.015 1918-1918/com.instantley.messenger W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)`

Comment: Try printing the file path and check whether you are using the pathname correctly

Comment: I'll suggest to check this http://www.technotalkative.com/android-read-text-file-from-sd-card/

Answer (score 3):

Try it without the file: prefix:

```
file = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instantley/IMG_20160523_170354803382833.jpg");
```